# No WPML Language Switcher in menu of custom archive pages

Tags: menu, header, wpml

I have some custom archive pages in my Avada child theme. I copied the Avada archive template files to my Avada Child and modified them to my needs. I haven’t changed the get_header part in the template files.

Now the problem is, that the WPML Language Switcher doesn’t show on these custom archive pages.

Comment: Theme support solved the issue. It is in the WPML -> Settings page